# Как из двух баз сделать одну?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Получилось так, что одну и ту базу дорабатывали на двух машинах. В обеих встречаются повторяющиеся значения; названия таблиц одинаковые, кол-во таблиц одно и то же, но есть и уникальные значения. Как из двух баз сделать третью с уникальными значениями обеих баз? Спасибо!

Comment: Боюсь, придётся ручками всё делать... может, у меня удача не прокачана, но  мне пока ни одного более-менее приличного инструмента слияния баз на глаза не попадалось.

Comment: А если запрос правильный накатать? Ну, скажем, найти разницу между таблицами (без учета id - а, например, по "столбцу-2 после id"). Это пойдет для уникальных значений. Потом запросы по повторам. Потом оба запроса отработать. Я просто даже плохо себе представляю, как это провернуть в phpmyadmin. Что нужно сделать? Импортировать обе базы, ок, потом отработать запросы описанные выше и сделать INSERT?

Comment: Или, к примеру, просто тупо свести две таблицы с одним названием и вывести уникальные значения, затем полученные значения добавить в db_3.tb?

Comment: Да слить данные - это фигня. SELECT INTO OUTFILE + LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE. Проблемы начнутся, когда потребуется при этом не потерять внешние ключи. А если ещё выяснится, что тексты SP/UFD/триггеров или структуры таблиц расползлись - так вообще туши свет.